Error after UNION two tables in MS Access
I created Query based on UNION of two tables. After the UNION operation, instead of clickable attachments in the column appears the text "#error". Tables are from different sources (both from .accdb file).
Union is written in procedure in VBA code:
Public Sub CreateHoldsTable()
    
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb()
    
    
    Dim qdfCheck As DAO.QueryDef
    For Each qdfCheck In db.QueryDefs
        If qdfCheck.Name = "kw_holds" Then
            db.QueryDefs.Delete "kw_holds"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next qdfCheck
    
    
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("kw_holds")
    
    
    Dim tableNumber As Integer
    tableNumber = 1 
    
    
    Dim tableCounter As Integer
    tableCounter = 0
    
    
    Dim fullQuery As String
    fullQuery = ""
    
    
    Do While True
        ' Utwórz nazwe tabeli
        Dim tableName As String
        tableName = "tb_hold" & tableNumber
        
        ' Sprawdz, czy tabela istnieje
        Dim tableExists As Boolean
        tableExists = False
        Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
        For Each tdf In db.TableDefs
            If tdf.Name = tableName Then
                tableExists = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next tdf
        
        
        If Not tableExists Then Exit Do
        
        
        Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(tableName)
        
         If tableCounter = 0 Then
            fullQuery = "SELECT * FROM " & tableName
            tableCounter = tableCounter + 1
         Else
            fullQuery = fullQuery & " UNION SELECT * FROM " & tableName
            tableCounter = tableCounter + 1
         End If
                      
        
        
        tableNumber = tableNumber + 1
    Loop
    
    qdf.SQL = fullQuery
    
End Sub

Both tables has same datatypes and when they're separate they're working. Other columns working correctly only "Attachement" has #error problem

What is the data type of Attachement column?

It's named Attachment

Not its name, its datatype ... (if you are correcting my spelling I am just using yours ... Other columns working correctly only "Attachement" has #error problem)

It's datatype - "Attachment". It's datatype to input files like photos, videos, datasheets etc.

Have you tried this union query without using vba?

Attachments are multivalued fields which cannot be used in UNION queries.

Yes this is my thought too ... attachment is really "attachments".

Yes I tried and there is the same problem

So there is any possibility to UNION (or do similar operations) tables with multivalued fields?

Maybe with an explicit SELECT of all columns instead of SELECT *, and then Attachment.X, Attachment.Y, ... for the attachment field (that's called explode-select)?

I confirmed that expanding the Attachment field will work in UNION (Attachment.FileName). If multiple items are stored in the field, there will be a record for each. The field will no longer be 'clickable'. Storing a lot of files in db uses up Access 2GB limit. Consider saving files in external folder and store only filename/path.

Is it possible to store path (or many paths) in Access and make it "clickable"?

Not clickable in table or query. Would require form.
